# This message uses a character set that is not supported by the InternetService?

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, encoding, header

I am using Spring `JavaMailSender` for sending mail from our web-application. Until now it works great, except for this case: one of our customers reported that their email client can't read the characters in email, and show:

> This message uses a character set that is not supported by the
>   Internet Service.  To view the original message content,  open the
>   attached message. If the text doesn't display correctly, save the
>   attachment to disk, and then open it using a viewer that can display
>   the original character set.

The strange thing is that only one person see this error. Others see the emails just fine. The troubled user is using Hotmail.

I searched through several forums, most of them are about frustrated customers about their email clients, but there's not many solutions/work arounds for server side. Some say that it's because of an in-the-way SMTP server doesn't support Unicode, but I don't think it's the case...

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@abc.abc","Hoang Long"));
helper.setReplyTo("abc@abc.abc");
helper.setTo(student.getEmail());           
helper.setSubject(emailSubject);
helper.setCc(studioParameterService.getAllCCEmailAddress(studio.getId()));
helper.setSentDate(new Date());
helper.setText(emailContent, true);

for (String filePath : attachFileList) {
FileSystemResource attachFile = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
   helper.addAttachment(attachFile.getFilename(), attachFile);
}           
mailSender.send(helper.getMimeMessage());
```

Comment: Does this message has some unicode characters, if so then you need to have UTF-8 support to your message, while sending mail as well as for view client.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal: how to get UTF-8 support? I think that's default